# Why is my_a.disp() not giving null or any error?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Below is the code:

```
class A;
  task disp();
         $display("This is Class A");
  endtask
endclass

class EA extends A;
  virtual task disp();
         $display("This is Extended Class A");
  endtask
endclass

program main();
  EA my_ea;
  A my_a;
  initial
        begin
           my_a=new();
           my_ea=new();   //line 19
           my_a=my_ea;    //line 20
           my_a.disp();
        end
endprogram
```

The child object in this example is not fixed with its method code during construction assignment because its method is virtual, someone please tell me why the output of the code is

> This is Class A

or just what is really happening at lines 19 and 20 during runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Handle `my_a` always references the `disp` task from class `A`, not the extended class.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 8.14 *Overridden members*:

> To call the overridden method via a base class object ... , the method needs to be declared **virtual** (see 8.20).

This is why `my_a.disp()` prints:

> This is Class A

If you want to use `disp` from the extended class, you should declare `disp` in class `A` as `virtual`:

```
class A;
  virtual task disp();
         $display("This is Class A");
  endtask
endclass
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the term *child object* indicates a misunderstanding that many people have about *class inheritance*.

Class `A` and `EA` are both class types. Type `EA` is an extension of type `A` which means `EA` includes all of the class members in type `A`. When constructing a class object of type `EA`, there is just one object containing all of the members in both `A` and `EA` (by *members* I mean class variables, functions and tasks).

`my_a` is a class variable that *may* hold a handle to an object of type `A` or any object of a type extended from `A`. However, `my_a` can only reference class members known by type `A` even though the object handle stored in `my_a` might contain a handle to an extended object like it does in your example.

Since `my_a.disp()` is defined as a *non-virtual* method in `A`, it prints "This is Class A". If you added the `virtual` keyword to the function definition in class A, then it would call the function defined in `EA`.